# Is there a way to implement multiple cursors in monaco editor?

Tags: angular, monaco-editor

I'm integrating Angular4 with Monaco editor now.
In order to simulate online editor (ex. Google docs), I want to create multiple cursors for different users. I use [ngx-monaco-editor](https://github.com/atularen/ngx-monaco-editor#readme) in my project, and call setPosition() to set cursor, but it dose not work for multiple cursors.

```
ngOnInit() {

this.socket.userConnect().subscribe((data) => {
  this.authenticateService.showNotification('top', 'center', 'success', data);
});

this.socket.userDisconnect().subscribe((data) => {
  this.authenticateService.showNotification('top', 'center', 'warning', data);
});

this.socket.getMessages('new-message').subscribe((data: Message) => {
  this.editor.setValue(data.content);
  data.position.column += 1;
  this.editor.setPosition(data.position);
});}
```